# Http POST Error 404 eventhough the URL is correct

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring

I am trying to make a `http.post` from my service to my controller, but apparently it they can't find each other.

Service

```
export class CarServiceService {

  private usersUrl: string;

  readonly httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN": "http://localhost:4200",
      "ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS": "true"
    })
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.usersUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
  }
  public save(car: Car) {
    return this.http.post(this.usersUrl+'/api/car/create-car', car, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/car")
public class CarController {

    private final CarRepository carRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CarController(CarRepository carRepository) {

        this.carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/create-car")
    @ResponseBody
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public void addCars(@RequestBody final car car) {
        this.carRepository.save(car);
    }
}
```

So the URL should is obviously `http://localhost:8080/api/car/create-car` however when trying to run it, I get the error `POST http://localhost:8080/api/car/create-car 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: The port is incorrect in your error message (4200), the code you show us is not the one executed in your frontend code.

Comment: can I know why you are setting the `ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN` and `ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` headers? These headers are part of the response entity, not a request, and hence is the server's responsibility to provide, not you as a client.

Comment: Can you also include the html template code? Are you using the `action` attribute on the form? Looking at your error message, the post request goes to `http://localhost:4200/api/car/create-car` instead of your backend which is hosted on port 8080.

Comment: Big sorry guys, the error message was misleading cause I still had it copied from a previous test. I changed it now, it does indeed show port 8080 in the error message. For @Ryednap : it was part of a solution I had to implement before as I kept getting CORS-Policy related errors. I have since solved it differently so I assume I could also leave the headers out.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I am using a modal, that upon pressing a "confirm" button, calls the save-method of the service. So the call to the service doesn't come from the html but rather from the component.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
public "type of your object" save(car: Car) {
    return this.http.post(this.usersUrl+'/api/car/create-car', car, this.httpOptions);
}
```

You didn't mention the return type of your object.